# ExpressJS & Jade + Post method and redirecting to a path

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, node.js, express

I'm new to node, express and jade and I'm making a small app that asks for a name and a password with a simple form and then redirects the user to the path that belongs to their username.

Here's the code for doing that:

Express first part (app.js):

```
(...)

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

(...)
```

Jade part (index.jade):

```
p Log In
form(method='post', action='/')

p
  label User 
  input(type='text',name='user')
p
  label Password 
  input(type='password', name='pass')
p
  input(type='submit', name='submit')
```

Express second part (app.js):

```
(...)

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    //Handle request form
    res.render('user', {
        locals: {
            user: req.body.user
        }
    })
});

(...)
```

For example:

username: roger

Passwor: 1234

Submit

Then when clicks submit I wanna redirect the user to:

http://mysite.com/roger

I hope that I've explained myself as well as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
res.redirect('roger');
```

Then you'll need another router to handle the rendering part:

```
app.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
  res.render('user');
});
```

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods

Comment: The link is broken